# Still using dataset?

Tags: sql, .net, visual-studio, ado.net, data-access-layer

I'm a fossil I know. I still use dataset, Datatable, Datarow, Dataview and so on.

Having been around since the VB 4 days, I have seen many different data accesses come and go. I consider the dataset with associated methods and commands to be the best, probably because I know it inside and out. It is so easy to throw up a data table with different content, eg read an xml file, extract data from a data table and more.

I know I should move on to EF and EF core and I've tried many times but keep falling back. Think the dataset is faster, you have better control and can affect exactly what you want. Probably a knowledge issue on my part?

What is the situation with ADO.NET, what is the future? From what I have understood, EF and EF core are built on ADO.NET so reasonably it should remain in the future?!

Why I ask is that I ran into problem when I updated to .NET 8. The generated designer code in Visual Studio gave warnings as per this link https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/34893. This error was easily circumvented by setting up the dataset in code instead. Is it just that Microsoft just wants to remove formatter-based serialization and the dataset itself will remain? What do the rest of you think (or know)? and are there any others out there who still use this fossil dataaccess and like it more than EF, EFCore and other ORMs?

Comment: Well, I for my part don't like ORMs at all. Instead of dealing with SQL a 4GL, the data access is muddled through with tree-like structures making things much more complicated than need be. It is for a reason that people call these "obfuscation layers" I've seen people fighting with their ORM for years to circumvent all the issues and slow data access it caused. I'd say "lesson learned; get back to direct access via dataset". I am curious what others will say.

Comment: I get that feeling too, it becomes more cumbersome to do what I want quickly. Especially if I only want to save some data in a simple database with a few tables. I'm also curious about what others think.

Comment: I am old school like yourself, and do still maintain a large code base which still uses Datasets etc. Most of our data access requirements are fairly simple, and datasets still work fine for these. When doing more complicated things, it can be easier/more natural to use proper c# classes, so you can easily use inheritance, interfaces, "proper" nullable types etc.  We built a layer which reads/writes to/from c# classes, a bit like an early crude Dapper. I quite like Dapper's philosophy - it's the right level of abstraction for me, and is what I'd use today if I was starting a new project.

Answer (score 4):

If it works for you, nobody is going to pry it out of your hands (at least... this week), but yes the world has moved on.

DataSet is absolutely not faster - quite the opposite: because it has to support arbitrary data shapes every query, it involves a lot of inefficiencies and indirections on data storage/access, and additional constant CPU time when accessing members by name (which is how you normally want to access them).

Tools like EF have been evolved hugely, but if you love your SQL and want to keep things simple, tools like Dapper can allow you to gain the efficiencies of a typed object model while still keeping tight control over your commands (but: without having to fight ADO.NET's command API yourself).

Comment: I probably meant that I consider it a faster way to do what I want, not that the dataset itself would be faster. I wrote a little unclearly, I saw it now.

Thanks for the tip with Dapper. Might be something to check out.

Mikael

Comment: @Mikael for a development time perspective: Dapper is hard to beat: define a type with properties for your columns (this can even be a "record" type), then just `connection.Query<YourType>(sql, args)` - job done